# Cannot evaluate whether a SUM is null or even greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query here:

```
select 
 WorkedHours =  
     (SELECT 
    
        CASE WHEN SUM(BillableSeconds) is not null
          THEN SUM(BillableSeconds)
          ELSE 0
        END 
      FROM Worklog WHERE IssueId = 188625
     )

from Worklog  where IssueId=188625
```

When I pass an `IssueId` that does match the criteria, the `CASE` works, but when I willingly pass an `IssueId` that I know will return no rows, 0 is not being returned.

I get this in SQL studio:

[image]

The idea here is to determine whether the sum is NULL, 0 or greater so a CAST to decimal doesn't yield an error.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Well, the outer `WHERE` will preclude the sum from getting returned at all, obviously. For clarity, why not just assign to a `@WorkedHours` variable first and then unconditionally `SELECT COALESCE(@WorkedHours, 0) AS WorkedHours`?

Comment: You have no result because there is no row, you have to find a way to always have a row, that is for example select from issues table rather than worklog table in the outermost query, and use coalesce like said in the comment from @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want this:

```
select COALESCE(SUM(BillableSeconds), 0) as WorkedHours
from Worklog 
where IssueId = 188625;
```

This is an aggregation query that always returns one row, even if the `where` clause filters everything out.

In your version, the outer query returns one row for every matching row in the table.  If no rows match, no row is returned.

Comment: @Larnu . . . That is very easily checked:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2732c2dee815db78b2f8c8a7cdd1745.